# Poppy Humanoid Bot import packages error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, macos-sierra

I am currently on macOS sierra using python 2.7 and installed all the packages required for poppy-humanoid.

```
sudo pip install poppy-humanoid
sudo pip install poppy
sudo pip install poppy-creature
```

Every module is successfully installed.

### Output of pip search 'poppy' is:

```
poppy-4dof-arm-mini (1.0.4)       - Poppy 4 dof arm mini Software Library
poppy-creature (1.8.2)            - Abstract Poppy Creature Software Library
poppy-ergo (1.0rc2)               - Poppy Ergo Software Library
poppy-ergo-jr (1.7.0rc1)          - Poppy Ergo Jr Software Library
poppy-humanoid (1.2.0rc1)         - Poppy Humanoid Software Library
poppy-ui (0.1)                    - Horizon Plugin to work with Poppy's CDN
                                    API
poppy-torso (1.1.5)               - Poppy Torso Software Library
poppy (0.5.1)                     - Physical optics propagation (wavefront
                                    diffraction) for optical simulations,
                                    particularly of telescopes.
poppy_inverse_kinematics (1.3.1)  - An inverse kinematics library aiming
                                    performance and modularity
poppycdn (1.0.13)                 - A modular, vendor-neutral API, that wraps
                                    provisioning instructions for all CDN
                                    vendors that support it.
spoppy (2.1.2)                    - A lightweight spotify CLI
```

But error is coming when i am trying to import these packages.

```
>>> import poppy.creature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named poppy.creature
```

Can someone please provide a workaround to successfully import these packages.

I have tried other workaround like providing the permission, extending the PYHTONPATH but no good

Comment: You installed `poppy-creature`, then tried to import `poppy.creature`. Does `import poppy-creature` work?

Comment: No its not working....No module named poppy-creature

Comment: Can I just check: what are the outputs of `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: I'll update u in evening because i m not having the laptop right now.

Comment: which pip --> /usr/local/bin/pip
which python --> /usr/bin/python

Comment: Looks like that's your problem. Do you only have the system pythons installed, or did you also install Python yourself from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, i have manually installed python 3.6 also.

Comment: That's peculiar. Hopefully one last thing should do it: Can you tell me the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: --> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a Python 2.7 that you installed from the Python website, along with the built-in Python 2.7. Your `pip` is installing modules for the 2.7 you installed, but typing in `python` runs the built-in 2.7.10, which is why it says not found. So, it *should* work if you type in `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of just `python`. If that works, you can edit your `~/.bash_profile` file to `alias python='/usr/local/bin/python'`, so that you don't need to type in the full path every single time.

Comment: No, i have only python3.6 installed other than default one(python 2.7).